# SIGKILL in a spoj-LKS

Tags: c, runtime-error, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, sigkill

While submitting the solution it shows a runtime error SIGKILL .I don't know why!!! Please help...!! I am not going to bother about TLE,I just want to know what is the reason for SIGKILL.And after that you may suggest me any faster procedure to solve this problem more efficiently.Please help, I have been stuck to this problem for too long time but I can't find how is that runtime error coming.
Here is my code::

`#include<stdio.h>`

```
//#define max(a,b) a>b?a:b
int max (int a,int  b){
     if (a>b)
        return a;
     else return b;

}
int V[500];
int W[500];
int F[501][1000001];



int knapsack(int n,int cap){
    if (n==0 || cap==0){
        F[n][cap]=0;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (cap<1000001){
        if (F[n][cap]!=0)
            return F[n][cap];
        else {
            if (W[n-1]>cap){
                 F[n][cap]=knapsack(n-1,cap);
             }
             else {
                 F[n][cap]=max(V[n-1]+knapsack(n-1,cap-W[n-1]),knapsack(n-1,cap));
             }

             return F[n][cap];
        }
    }
    else {
        if (W[n-1]>cap){
            return knapsack(n-1,cap);
            }
        else {
            return max(V[n-1]+knapsack(n-1,cap-W[n-1]),knapsack(n-1,cap));
        }

    }

}

main() {
    int k,n,i;
    scanf("%d %d",&k,&n);

    for (i =0 ;i<n ;i++){
        scanf("%d %d",&V[i],&W[i]);

    }

    printf("%d\n",knapsack(n,k));

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for SIGKILL is your array F[501][1000001];

This is because global variables are given memory from heap.
Now memory limit of LKS on Spoj is 1536 MB which is equivalent to 1.6E9 bytes.
As int is of 4 bytes so maximum size of int array can be approx 4E8 and you have declared an int array of 5E8 size. So reducing your array size can get you rid of SIGKILL.

To solve the problem, what you have to do is to make an array for dp of 2 rows and then compute the answer.

```
int dp[2][2000001];
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you @utkarsh13 for your answer.I didn't get your way to solve the problem ,but let me try this to understand.Thank you again =D

Comment: Refer to this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246670/0-1-knapsack-dynamic-programming-optimazion-from-2d-matrix-to-1d-matrix/26325369#26325369